# android - Toolbar not displaying in activity

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, material-design

working on a wallpaper app and working on moving to API 21 and removing the ActionBar in favor of Toolbar. That being said, I am trying to use the v7-support library. What happens is basically there is a grey outline of where the toolbar *should* be, but it never appears.

WallpaperActivity.java:

```
package com.death2all110.blisspapers;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.UrlImageViewCallback;
import com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.UrlImageViewHelper;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WallpaperActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public final String TAG = "BlissPapers";
    protected static final String MANIFEST = "wallpaper_manifest.xml";
    protected static final int THUMBS_TO_SHOW = 4;

    /*
     * pull the manifest from the web server specified in config.xml or pull
     * wallpaper_manifest.xml from local assets/ folder for testing
     */
    public static final boolean USE_LOCAL_MANIFEST = false;

    ArrayList<WallpaperCategory> categories = null;
    ProgressDialog mLoadingDialog;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark));

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wallpaper);

        mLoadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mLoadingDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mLoadingDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mLoadingDialog.setMessage("Retreiving wallpapers from server...");

        mLoadingDialog.show();
        new LoadWallpaperManifest().execute();

        Toolbar ab = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(ab);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Bliss Papers");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        UrlImageViewHelper.setErrorDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.drawable.ic_error));

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Wallpaper.wallpapersCreated = 0;
    }

    protected void loadPreviewFragment() {
        WallpaperPreviewFragment fragment = new WallpaperPreviewFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }


    public static class WallpaperPreviewFragment extends Fragment {

        static final String TAG = "PreviewFragment";
        WallpaperActivity mActivity;
        View mView;

        public int currentPage = -1;
        public int highestExistingIndex = 0;
        Button back;
        Button next;
        TextView pageNum;
        ThumbnailView[] thumbs;
        protected int selectedCategory = 0; // *should* be <ALL> wallpapers

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            mActivity = (WallpaperActivity) getActivity();
            next(); // load initial page
        }

        public void setCategory(int cat) {
            selectedCategory = cat;
            currentPage = -1;
            next();
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            mView = inflater.inflate(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.layout.activity_wallpaper, container, false);

            back = (Button) mView.findViewById(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.id.backButton);
            next = (Button) mView.findViewById(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.id.nextButton);
            pageNum = (TextView) mView.findViewById(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.id.textView1);

            thumbs = new ThumbnailView[THUMBS_TO_SHOW];
            thumbs[0] = (ThumbnailView) mView.findViewById(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.id.imageView1);
            thumbs[1] = (ThumbnailView) mView.findViewById(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.id.imageView2);
            thumbs[2] = (ThumbnailView) mView.findViewById(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.id.imageView3);
            thumbs[3] = (ThumbnailView) mView.findViewById(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.id.imageView4);

            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    next();
                }
            });

            back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    previous();
                }
            });

            return mView;
        }

        public ArrayList<WallpaperCategory> getCategories() {
            return mActivity.categories;
        }

        protected Wallpaper getWallpaper(int realIndex) {
            return getCategories().get(selectedCategory).getWallpapers().get(realIndex);
        }

        protected void setThumbs() {
            for (ThumbnailView v : thumbs)
                v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            final int numWallpapersInCategory = getCategories().get(selectedCategory)
                    .getWallpapers().size();
            boolean enableForward = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < thumbs.length; i++) {
                final int realIndex = (currentPage * thumbs.length + i);
                if (realIndex >= (numWallpapersInCategory - 1)) {
                    enableForward = false;
                    break;
                }

                Wallpaper w = getWallpaper(realIndex);
                thumbs[i].setOnClickListener(null);
                thumbs[i].getName().setText(w.getName());
                thumbs[i].getAuthor().setText(w.getAuthor());
                UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(thumbs[i].getThumbnail(), w.getThumbUrl(),
                        com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.drawable.ic_placeholder, new ThumbnailCallBack(w, realIndex));
            }

            back.setEnabled(currentPage != 0);
            next.setEnabled(enableForward);
        }

        public void next() {
            getNextButton().setEnabled(false);
            pageNum.setText(getResources().getString(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.string.page) + " " + (++currentPage + 1));

            setThumbs();
        }

        public void previous() {
            pageNum.setText(getResources().getString(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.string.page) + " " + (--currentPage + 1));

            setThumbs();
        }

        protected void skipToPage(int page) {
            if (page < currentPage) {
                while (page < currentPage) {
                    previous(); // should subtract page
                }
            } else if (page > currentPage) {
                while (page > currentPage) {
                    next();
                }
            }
        }

        public void jumpTo() {
            // View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_jumpto,
            // null);
            // final EditText e = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.pageNumber);
            // AlertDialog.Builder j = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            // j.setTitle(R.string.jump2);
            // j.setView(view);
            // j.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new
            // DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            //
            // public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // skipToPage(Integer.parseInt(e.getText().toString()));
            // }
            // });
            // j.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new
            // DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            //
            // public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // dialog.cancel();
            // }
            // });
            // j.create().show();
        }

        protected View getThumbView(int i) {
            if (thumbs != null && thumbs.length > 0)
                return thumbs[i];
            else
                return null;
        }

        protected Button getNextButton() {
            return next;
        }

        protected Button getPreviousButton() {
            return back;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        }

        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.id.jump:
                    jumpTo();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }

        class ThumbnailCallBack implements UrlImageViewCallback {

            Wallpaper wall;
            int index;

            public ThumbnailCallBack(Wallpaper wall, int index) {
                this.wall = wall;
                this.index = index;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoaded(ImageView imageView, Drawable loadedDrawable, String url,
                    boolean loadedFromCache, boolean error) {

                final int relativeIndex = index % 4;
                if (!error) {
                    getThumbView(relativeIndex).setOnClickListener(
                            new ThumbnailClickListener(wall));
                }
                getThumbView(relativeIndex).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (relativeIndex == 3)
                    getNextButton().setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        class ThumbnailClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
            Wallpaper wall;

            public ThumbnailClickListener(Wallpaper wallpaper) {
                this.wall = wallpaper;
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent preview = new Intent(mActivity, Preview.class);
                preview.putExtra("wp", wall.getUrl());
                startActivity(preview);
            }
        }
    }



    public static String getDlDir(Context c) {
        String configFolder = getResourceString(c, com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.string.config_wallpaper_download_loc);
        if (configFolder != null && !configFolder.isEmpty()) {
            return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), configFolder)
                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/";
        } else {
            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        }
    }

    public static String getSvDir(Context c) {
        String configFolder = getResourceString(c, com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.string.config_wallpaper_sdcard_dl_location);
        if (configFolder != null && !configFolder.isEmpty()) {
            return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), configFolder)
                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/";
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected String getWallpaperDestinationPath() {
        String configFolder = getResourceString(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.string.config_wallpaper_sdcard_dl_location);
        if (configFolder != null && !configFolder.isEmpty()) {
            return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), configFolder)
                    .getAbsolutePath();
        }
        // couldn't find resource?
        return null;
    }

    protected String getResourceString(int stringId) {
        return getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(stringId);
    }

    public static String getResourceString(Context c, int id) {
        return c.getResources().getString(id);
    }

    private class LoadWallpaperManifest extends
            AsyncTask<Void, Boolean, ArrayList<WallpaperCategory>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<WallpaperCategory> doInBackground(Void... v) {

            try {
                InputStream input = null;

                if (USE_LOCAL_MANIFEST) {
                    input = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(MANIFEST);
                } else {
                    URL url = new URL(getResourceString(com.death2all110.blisspapers.R.string.config_wallpaper_manifest_url));
                    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                    connection.connect();
                    // this will be useful so that you can show a typical
                    // 0-100%
                    // progress bar
                    int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

                    // download the file
                    input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                }
                OutputStream output = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(
                        MANIFEST, MODE_PRIVATE);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();

                // file finished downloading, parse it!
                ManifestXmlParser parser = new ManifestXmlParser();
                return parser.parse(new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), MANIFEST),
                        getApplicationContext());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Exception!", e);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<WallpaperCategory> result) {
            categories = result;
            if (categories != null)
                loadPreviewFragment();

            mLoadingDialog.cancel();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is activity_wallpaper.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <View
        android:id="@+id/strut"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/strut"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/back" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/strut"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/next" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/backButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/page" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <com.death2all110.blisspapers.ThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <com.death2all110.blisspapers.ThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <com.death2all110.blisspapers.ThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <com.death2all110.blisspapers.ThumbnailView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Bliss" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

If I remove the setContentView from the onCreate method, I get an error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference

Any ideas on what I can do to correct this?

Screenshot:[image: Toolbar Displays, but no Title]

Comment: You don't need to call `getSupportActionBar().show();`, I'm not sure if this is the solution to your issue though.

Comment: @Philio It was an attempt to get it to show. I'll remove it though.

Comment: I would also suggest removing `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);` you don't need this either to use a toolbar

Comment: Try commenting out everything except the setContentView and setSupportActionBar (and corresponding code) and see if it works.

Comment: @Philio Did that, and moved toolbar to the onCreate method and same issue, just an outline of where the toolbar should be

Comment: what r u building with - gradle? Ur code in 'onCreate' looks good.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html  https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/  review those 2 links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a android.supprt.v7.widget.Toolbar to your layout and then do this in the onCreate method of your ActionBarActivity

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActitionBar(toolbar);
```

Also, make sure your theme uses Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar (or Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar)

Comment: I already have that in my WallpaperActivity and activity_wallpaper.xml

Comment: Well I fixed my style to set the correct parent theme. And now the Toolbar displays. But I can't get the title to appear. I removed android:windowNoTitle and the windowNoActionBar lines from styles.xml. I also tried getSupportActionBar.setTitle("Title"); and getSupportActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true); but the title flashes up and then disappears

Comment: Got everything solved. Using the regular material theme instead of AppCompat and using the regular toolbar API. This allowed what I wanted as well as the the title to stay. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

FWIW - i just retrofitted some ABS stuff to the newer Toolbar stuff that you are on and had some issues with the Title not showing up in all Frgments, activities.... Some worked some did not. Very frustrating to have varied outcomes.  Had to replicate the following code in places where i did not think it should be needed due to inheritance and due to calls to 'super.onCreate()'..

```
 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

After populated the above code everywhere in those activities/frags where it did NOT show up, the issue resolved.

Really odd that ur title flashes up then disappear.. something is repainting the view!

Comment: Just tried this. Same issues. This is getting really frustrating, lol.

Comment: what about trying at point further down call stack... onStart, onResume  ??

Comment: Gotta be a bug in the AppCompat library. I switched to using the material theme and API21 without the app compat stuff and everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I needed to

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>
```

in my activity's layout file since I had my toolbar layout defined in its own xml file.